# Eclipse RCP Repeating Job, ProgressMonitor in ProgressView -> not showing next times

Tags: eclipse-rcp, progress, operation

I have Eclipse RCP based application, with Eclipse ProgressView for tracking JOBs.

I have implemented RepeatingJob according to:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_create_a_repeating_background_task%3F

1st time of running my repeating JOB I can see progressMonitor working in ProgressView. Problem is when next time this repeating job is started then I see no ProgressMonitor.

In the beginning of operation I start monitor.beginTask("Blabla..whatever..."), I do not stop IProgressMonitor in my operation after its finished.

I dont know where could be problem.

Comment: Could you at least post your code? Do you call monitor.done() in the end of execution?

Answer (score 0):

If you put a breakpoint in the 'run' method of your job class, you'll see, that it is actually running, but display is not refreshed. Try to put your thread sleep for a while:

```
protected IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            monitor.beginTask("repeating...", 1);
            schedule(3000);
            monitor.done();
            return Status.OK_STATUS;
        }
```

Comment: actually I tried as you wrote and even with debug mode, and ProgressMonitor not shown, only Icon & State change from "ZZZ"..(Sleeping) to "ProgressIcon"...(Running)

Comment: Note: I use Eclipse Indigo 3.7.2 and not Juno !